# Showing detail from a ListView

Tags: android, listview

What is the correct way of showing a new View with more detailed information from a ListView in Android? It's a topic that I can't find a solid answer for in [either](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Beginning-Android-2-Mark-Murphy/dp/1430226293/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1287480581&sr=1-4) of [these](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Android-Application-Development-Programming-Google/dp/0596521472/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1287480581&sr=1-6) Android books.

For example a list of contact names, one is selected and a view shows their full details.

Do I launch a new activity for this or use a ViewFlipper?

Comment: Where did you read that launching a new activity is a wrong approach?

Comment: @Maragues It doesn't, I've updated as I misread the event lifecycle on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html as being for the app, not just a view/page. Though you could argue some of those events should be in an application class such as onPause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is right. It's the recommended one.
When designing an activity, it's suggested to use this paradigm:

One activity = one thing to do.

- Viewing the list
- Viewing the details

On the Notepad tutorial app, a new activity is launched to view the details of a list item.

Anyway, the ViewFlipper is another possible approach that keeps all the content in a single activity. This approach is suitable if you manage the Back key correctly.

Comment: As a side question, is the best practice to pass a state object (the listview example) using a static variable on a class, or in the constructor?